# How can I repair synaptic-pkexec

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-mate

When I try to run synaptic-pkexec, I get this.

```
andy@7 ~> synaptic-pkexec
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR com.ubuntu.pkexec.synaptic ===
Authentication is required to run the Synaptic Package Manager
Authenticating as: andy,,, (andy)
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
andy@7 ~>
```

Comment: Are you running this inside a mate desktop, or at a CLI terminal? Is `mate-polkit` running? what is the output of `pgrep -af polkit`?

Comment: andy@7 ~> pgrep -af polkit
1039 /usr/libexec/polkitd --no-debug
2409 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/polkit-mate/polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1
@steeldriver